# Discrete Math- Modular Congruence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

The problem is asking to find c given that-

c ≡ 13a(mod19) and the variable  a ≡ 11 (mod19).

I've tried to solve this using algebra and using the theorems but I can't seem to work it out.

Any suggestions?

Edit: 
   0 ≤ c ≤ 18

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no problem:
$$ c\equiv 13\times 11=143\equiv 10 \pmod{19}. $$
Thus $c=10+19k,\enspace k\in\mathbf Z$. The only solution between $0$ and $18$ is for $k=0$, i.e. $c=10$.

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: $36=9\times 4$, plus the fact that congruences are compatible with addition and multiplication. What isn't clear?

Comment: Apologies. I forgot to add another part of the problem which is 0≤c≤18.

Comment: You're welcome. See my updated answer.

Comment: What about the variable a and what it's congruent to? Is that obsolete?

Comment: I used the variable $a$ and its congruence class ($4$). Btw, you've changed the problem data.

Comment: The data is the same, just written differently. Sorry if the first way confused you.

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer.